# Comment on a line in Github without a commit?

Tags: github, comments

In github, you can comment on lines in a commit. Is there a way to comment on a line, while viewing a file in a branch, without having a particular commit?

Comment: What would happen if the file changes and the line numbers change with it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to comment on a line in Github without a commit.

But you can create links to lines in your file (click on line and copy link on browser bar). For example you can use this links in your issues to discuss about code line:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/README.md?plain=1#L1

**Update**

You can also hold shift to obtain a link to a block of lines

Comment: Is there a public repository service that allows comment on lines or whole files?

Comment: Here is the proper way to comment on github : https://help.github.com/articles/commenting-on-the-diff-of-a-pull-request

Comment: Thanks @PieterEnnes it is very important information. Can update answer and add this information?

Comment: @VicJordan That link is for commenting on pull requests. If there's no pull request, a link as Ferid suggests, possibly in a new issue, looks like the way to go.

Comment: It is of utmost importance to use the [`y` keyboard shortcut](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/) before copying a link to any file. Otherwise it will copy the link with `master`, which may "degrade" with time

Comment: The link in this answer does not work anymore

Answer (score 9):

You should have at least one commit: your initial import ;-) So if you never touched the file afterwards, you can still browse your master branch (or wherever you did the initial import to).

To get to a commit of file, do as follows:

- open homepage of your repo, e.g. here [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails)
- browse to the file you like to comment, e.g. Rails' [.gitignore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/.gitignore) file
- there's a [button called history, click it](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/844e944465beb37bd19bdfdedc19eba54479f39e/.gitignore) to see latest commits of this file
- look for a commit and click the link with the revision ID

You should now be able to comment the file.

Comment: @JohnLehmann As it is not possible, I tried to provide a creative workaround. Why do you ask the same question again?

Comment: I find it more intuitive to click on 'blame' which will show which (current) line is part of which commit then click on the commit on the left to comment on the corresponding line.

Comment: At least with the current (2013-08-12) Github *history* web interface, it is not straightforward to locate the exact line in the file one would like to comment: A commit's history only shows those lines that have changed in this commit... Or is there a way to locate the last commit that made changes to a specified line?

Comment: @Abdull Yeah, you can use the Blame function, as Andre describes above

Answer (score 9):

This blog post provides a simple way to use github's built-in commenting features for this:
http://astrofrog.github.io/blog/2013/04/10/how-to-conduct-a-full-code-review-on-github/

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing, for a code review.

I ended up:

1. forking the repo
2. adding my comments in the source code (e.g. `// TODO: ...`)
3. making a pull request

Comment: I found that it was a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

The only way if you use a different tool for this job. I use Fisheye, or Review-Board for do pre-commit revision code.

Review Board is free, and handle better than Fisheye the pre-commit code.